# Barcode scanning broken

Tags: android, ios, qr-code, codenameone, barcode-scanner

Since the recent update for Codename one any barcode scanning seems to be broken.
On android the camera appears and scans the code but nothing happens when it returns to the app (that is none of the 3 callback functions are triggered).
On iOS the camera window doesn't even appear.
I'm using this library since it doesn't rely on an installed scanning app:
https://github.com/littlemonkeyltd/QRScanner

I had thought the inbuilt scanning functionality may have been removed and passed to this library, so I tried to include that too:
https://github.com/codenameone/cn1-codescan

However it still isn't working on Android. IOS refuses to build with the cn1-codescan library included.

Pretty sure this was all working last week, or the week before.

my code looks like this:

```
Log.p("Scanning QR code");
    QRScanner.scanQRCode(new ScanResult() {
        public void scanCompleted(String contents, String formatName, byte[] rawBytes) {
            Log.p("QR result:"+contents);
            QRResult(contents, formatName, rawBytes);
        }
        public void scanCanceled() {
            Log.p("scan canceled");
        }
        public void scanError(int errorCode, String message) {
            Log.p("error during scan: " + message);
            scanFailed();
        }
    });
```

**edit:**
Here are the android build hints added to codenameone_setting.properties when I add the libraries in:
`codename1.arg.android.xapplication=<activity android\:name\="com.dm.zbar.android.scanner.ZBarScannerActivity" android\:screenOrientation\="landscape" android\:label\="@string/app_name" />`

`codename1.arg.android.xpermissions=<uses-permission android\:name\="android.permission.CAMERA"/><uses-feature android\:name\="android.hardware.camera" android\:required\="false"/>`

`codename1.arg.android.proguardKeep=\  -keep class net.sourceforge.zbar.** {*;}`

Comment: As far as I know the weekend update should have fixed that regression, I'll have a look. FYI only the library is supposed to work, the builtin barcode scanning shouldn't work.

Comment: the latest cn1-codescan.cn1lib is causing a build error on iOS

Comment: Still not working on Android as of Today. I tried to build on version 3.4 to see if that was working and got this error:
"Version is no longer supported for pro users! Oldest supported version for pro users is 3.4"

Comment: The 3.4 issue seems like a bug, we'll fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you build against the "latest" barcode scanning should work. I'm assuming that you built against 3.5 and not the latest. It's possible that the regression in barcode scanning got into 3.5, this we verified that barcode/qr code scanning works with the latest on the build servers.

Comment: I just build again using the latest, and though this fixed my Facebook login issue, the QR callbacks are still not being fired.

Comment: also still getting a build error on iOS when including the latest version of cn1-codescan.cn1lib

Comment: If you are using the littlemonkey QR scanner delete the lib and reinstall it from the extensions menu, we updated it to work with our library instead of the system QR scanner.

Comment: Hey thanks, this has fixed the ios build issue and the callback is being fired. It's still not working on Android though. Just no callback being fired at all.

Comment: Are you targeting the Latest or a specific version? Make sure you target the latest.

Comment: I am targeting the latest and I pulled the libs using the extensions menu

Comment: I built the library and added some logs to the onActivityResult() method in IntentResultListener but it is not getting called at all

Comment: Odd. Any additional information you might have will be interesting. We'll try to reproduce it but I'm not sure if we have all the information.

Comment: Looks like one of the build hints wasn't properly included in the library's appended properties.  I have fixed the library now.  It should be available soon cn1 extensions.  In the mean time you can manually add the required build hint to your project.  `android.xapplication=<activity android:name="com.dm.zbar.android.scanner.ZBarScannerActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:label="@string/app_name" />`

Comment: Still doesn't seem to be working. When I pull the new libs it doesn't want to build saying there is an error with the manifest merging. if I try to use the old one with the above build hint it still isn't firing any of the callbacks. I will put together a minimal example and send that if it also isn't working.

Comment: So I've built this minimal example:  
http://pastebin.com/R6ppdn5E  
  
which produces the following build error:  
http://pastebin.com/rQeEYWrC  
  
I can't tell if it's working because I can't get it to build on android

Comment: Delete your existing `android.xapplication` & `android.xpermissions` build hint values. Then use refresh libs to set the value properly

Comment: I've tried that. My project will build, but there is still no callback being fired at all. The minimal example I've provided above wont build, it's still showing the same build error (Manifest merger failed) that I've linked above

Comment: Can you add the android.* build hints from the test project to the question above?

Comment: I have a guess about what might be causing it I think it's a conflict with the `<uses-feature android\:name\="android.hardware.camera" android\:required\="false"/>` line. I'll ask someone to look into it again.

Comment: FYI this should be fixed in current builds